# Jolokia crashes when response too big

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, jolokia

I'm trying to run this on my tomcat with Jolokia installed.

```
http://myserver/jolokia/read/Catalina:type=ThreadPool,name=*/
```

What I get is this

> {"error_type":"javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException","error":"javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException
>   : Exception invoking method
>   readBufSize","status":500,"stacktrace":"javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException:
>   Exception invoking method readBufSize\n\tat
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.getAttribute(BaseModelMBean.java:197)\n\tat
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:647)\n\tat
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)\n\tat
>   org.jolokia.handler.ReadHandler.getAttribute(ReadHandler.java:208)\n\tat
>   org.jolokia.handler.ReadHandler.fetchAttributes(ReadHandler.java:158)\n\tat
>   org.jolokia.handler.ReadHandler.fetchAttributesForMBeanPattern(ReadHandler.java:97)\n\tat
>   org.jolokia.handler.ReadHandler.doHandleRequest(ReadHandler.java:82)\n\tat
>   org.jolokia.handler.ReadHandler.doHandleRequest(ReadHandler.java:34)\n\tat
>   org.jolokia.handler.JsonRequestHandler.handleRequest(JsonRequestHandler.java:150)\n\tat
>   org.jolokia.backend.MBeanServerHandler.dispatchRequest(MBeanServerHandler.java:91)\n\tat
>   org.jolokia.backend.LocalRequestDispatcher.dispatchRequest(LocalRequestDispatcher.java:81)\n\tat
>   org.jolokia.backend.BackendManager.callRequestDispatcher(BackendManager.java:196)\n\tat
>   org.jolokia.backend.BackendManager.handleRequest(BackendManager.java:175)\n\tat
>   org.jolokia.http.HttpRequestHandler.executeRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:150)\n\tat
>   org.jolokia.http.HttpRequestHandler.handleGetRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:79)\n\tat
>   org.jolokia.http.AgentServlet$3.handleRequest(AgentServlet.java:239)\n\tat
>   org.jolokia.http.AgentServlet.handle(AgentServlet.java:200)\n\tat
>   org.jolokia.http.AgentServlet.doGet(AgentServlet.java:183)\n\tat
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)\n\tat
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)\n\tat
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)\n\tat
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)\n\tat
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)\n\tat
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721)\n\tat
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)\n\tat
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)\n\tat
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)\n\tat
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)\nCaused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProperties.getRxBufSize(SocketProperties.java:239)\n\tat
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.getReadBufSize(NioEndpoint.java:619)\n\tat
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)\n\tat
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)\n\tat
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.getAttribute(BaseModelMBean.java:190)\n\t...
>   38 more\n"}

It looks like Jolokia can't handle large responses. Any way I can fix the problem? I just need a few attributes but I couldn't figure out how to get 2 attributes in a single request.

Here is my jolokia version

> {"timestamp":1405453600,"status":200,"request":{"type":"version"},"value":{"protocol":"5.0","agent":"0.95","info":{"product":"tomcat","vendor":"Apache","version":"7.0.47"}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably not the full stack trace. It's not about that Jolokia can't handle large objects (well, if there is an issue, it's something of you sercer container), since you get a complete response. The reason (hidden in the "38 more") is that the method 'getReadBufSize' throws an exception.

You have two options, though:

- Use the query parameter `ignoreErrors=true` which is quite useful if you do bulk requests like this.
- You can indeed choose multiple attributes: For a GET request simply concatanate them with ',', for POST requests use an JSON Array. All is explained in the [reference manual](http://www.jolokia.org/reference/html/index.html). For your request:`http://myserver/jolokia/read/Catalina:type=ThreadPool,name=*/attr1,attr2` You need a post 1.0.0 Jolokia agent, though.

Comment: Thanks, since I updated my Jolokia Agent I'm able to get multiple attributes, so I don't run into this issue anymore.